# Split .dat large file

Tags: file, split

I received a file with .dat format. The file has 2GB and about 4 millions rows. I've tried to open with Excel/Notepad/Notepad++ but none of them could open the file, it's always an error associated with memory(I have 16GB ram). I also tried split the file with some apps but nothing too.

What else can I do?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you want to do with it? If you just want to view it, ``GVim`` might be able to.

Comment: Actually I want to open in Excel after split. Tks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Excel will be able to deal with that much data at the same time, I'm afraid. Perhaps you can get your hands on database software such as MS Access: they can work with really large data sets. An alternative is an editor for SQLite. Both of them are quite a bit more complex than Excel.

Comment: That's why I want to split the large file in smaller parts. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can split a file on lines using a programming language called [Python 3](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-342/) (download at the bottom of that page). Example script:

```
# Your input file name
filename = r"C:\path\to\input.dat" 
# Your new chunk files will be here. You must keep 
# the {:04}, because it will be replaced by a number.
chunknametemplate = r"C:\path\to\input-{:04}.dat"

# Number of bytes for each chunk, set this to something large
# like 10*1000*1000 (for 10 MB).
minchunksize = 10*1000*1000

f = open(filename, 'rb')

buf = b''
chunknum=1

def writechunk():
    global buf, chunknum
    open(chunknametemplate.format(chunknum), 'wb').write(buf)
    buf = b''
    chunknum += 1


while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if line == b'':
        break

    buf += line
    if len(buf) > minchunksize:
        writechunk()

# Write the last chunk
writechunk()
```